# Orderby with a string that contains part numbers and part letters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am using MSSQL ADO.NET and I need to sort order by employer code numercially although each order code has 2X letters in front of it.

For example:

```
HP1234
HP1233
HP1236
```

Essentially I am trying to seperate the numbers from the letters and order by either asc or desc just with the numbers to give some order. I wondered if anyone can advise on a good approach to do this withing an orderby clause.

Comment: is it always 2 characters and 4 numbers? or the 4 numbers could vary in quantity? if you know the first 2 characters are always to be omitted, just take the right for length minus 2 and cast to numeric.

Comment: Use order by on the column after using substring to remove the first two characters.

Comment: Its always two letters, the numbers vary in length. The first two are always letters and are to be omitted in the order by though not in the output.

Comment: If you had normalized data with each data element being its own column this would not be a problem at all. When you combine 2 pieces of data into a single column you violate 1NF and have all sort of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, RIGHT(employer_code, LEN(employer_code) - 2))
```

Comment: Thanks you namrehs. Really useful piece of scipt. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note I did not add any erro checking, but this would help if the pattern changed etc. Even though this is C#, you can convert the code to VB.

```
void Main()
{
    var arrayOfString = new string []{"HP1234","HP1233","HP1236"};
    var pat =@"(?<name>\d+)";
    Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var orderedItems =  arrayOfString.OrderBy(x=>{
        var match =  r.Match(x);

        return match.Groups["name"].Value;
    });

    foreach (var item in orderedItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

}
```

VB Code

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim arrayOfString = New String() {"HP1234", "HP1233", "HP1236"}
    Dim pat = "(?<name>\d+)"
    Dim r As New Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim orderedItems = arrayOfString.OrderBy(Function(x) GetSortOrder(x,r))

    For Each item As string In orderedItems
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next

End Sub

Function GetSortOrder(x , r)    
    Dim match = r.Match(x) 
    Return match.Groups("name").Value
End Function
```

Comment: C# is my language of choice, I assumed that the code written here is pretty simple to convert to VB. If the OP had issues with converting I definitely wouldn't mind converting for him. I gave him an alternative way of thinking of the solution. Since he is already using a ADO.Net he can also perform the sort in his client side code.